# Securing Connection String in Windows Azure Error: Failed to Decrypt

Tags: encryption, azure

I am getting a parse error message after following [this tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlazure/archive/2010/09/07/10058942.aspx). The error says

"Failed to decrypt using provider 'CustomProvider'. Error message from the provider: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: keyObject"

Any Ideas what's going on here?

Comment: I had the same error and my issue was this. "In case the Pkcs12ProtectedConfigurationProvider throws an ArgumentNullException with the parameter name of keyObject when you’re accessing the configuration, you probably have not imported the private part of the key (i.e. you chose the .cer file when importing)."from http://www.heikniemi.net/hardcoded/2013/06/encrypting-connection-strings-in-windows-azure-web-applications/

Answer (score 0):

I believe this problem occurs if the keys you have installed in your web server, does not have proper access rights.

I believe when you have installed the keys you must have the following commands:

- aspnet_regiis -px "CustomKeys" "C:\CustomKeys.xml" -pri
- aspnet_regiis -pi "CustomKeys" "C:\CustomKeys.xml"

I think the following steps are missing in the above blog as I could not find these important steps.

**Grant access to the ASP.NET application identity**

```
aspnet_regiis –pa “CustomKeys” “domain\your_service_AccountName”
```

The command should give the following output:

```
Adding ACL for access to the RSA Key container...Succeeded!
```

Above extra steps are defined here: [Encrypt Configuration Sections in ASP.NET 2.0 Using RSA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650304.aspx)
Also you can verify from the link above to see if something is missing in your steps.

Comment: What is "CustomKeys"?  What is "CustomKeys.xml"?